# Get values from a dataframe using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe x and it has 3 columns and 5 rows.

```
        Group 1 Group 2 Group 3
brandA  -1.4095 -0.9295 -0.6889 
brandB  -0.7400 -0.6498 -0.3269
brandC  -1.7454 -0.9119 -0.8219 
sizeM    0.5047 -3.4571  0.4003
sizeL   -1.3012 -5.9978 -0.2422
```

I need to create a loop to get b1 for brandA in Group 1(-1.4) and in group 2(-0.9) and in group 3(-0.6). And b2 for brandB in Group 1 ,2 and 3, and so on for b3. I tried to use a trivil get paste, but I don't know how to do it.

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  b1 <- get(paste("x"))[['Group', sep=""]] 
}
```

Comment: Thus you want a vector of `c("Group1 (-1.4095)", "Group1 (-0.9295)", ....)` for each row? Please include your expected output for row1.

Comment: actually I want to get b individually for each group

Comment: please clarify....what is `b`? Add your expected output.

Comment: How do you want your output structured??

Comment: I figured that I have to split the data frame to lists based on group. So the output should be lists y1, y2, y3

Answer (score 0):

Use `by` to split the data frame by rows and unlist them to create named vectors. `setNames` is to change the list names to what you want and then use `list2env` to build each element in the list to the global environment. Note that `b1`~`b3` are named vectors, not data frames with one row.

```
lst <- setNames(by(df[1:3,], 1:3, unlist), paste0("b", 1:3))
list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)

b1
#  Group1  Group2  Group3 
# -1.4095 -0.9295 -0.6889

b2
#  Group1  Group2  Group3 
# -0.7400 -0.6498 -0.3269

b3
#  Group1  Group2  Group3 
# -1.7454 -0.9119 -0.8219
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group1 = c(-1.4095, -0.74, -1.7454, 0.5047, -1.3012),
    Group2 = c(-0.9295, -0.6498, -0.9119, -3.4571, -5.9978),
    Group3 = c(-0.6889, -0.3269, -0.8219, 0.4003, -0.2422)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c("brandA", "brandB", "brandC", "sizeM", "sizeL"))
```